# Changes commited from Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I am committing changes from android studio into github and message appears that " succesfully committed 2 files ... ". But i cant see even a single change appearing on my repo on browser when I refresh it. Is there a way to know where those changes were committed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In git (and other distribution version control systems or DVCS), there is the concept of a 'local' and a 'remote' repository. You have only commited to your local repository, and not yet 'synced' to the remote repository (GitHub) - hence your changes are not yet displayed on GitHub.

Specifically in Git you create a *commit* against your local repository, and then you need to *push* your *commit(s)* to your *remote* repository (GitHub). For further reading see ['Syncing' at atlassian.com](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing).

### Pushing in Android Studio

To do this in Android Studio from the top menu choose `VCS` then `Git` then `Push` to bring up the 'Push commits dialog', review the information presented and press `Push` to push to GitHub.

See the [IntelliJ IDEA documentation for more information](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/pushing-changes-to-the-upstream-git-push.html) (Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition).

---

### Pushing from the CLI

To do this from the Git command line, execute

```
git push {remote-name} {branch-name}
```

In the vast majority of cases, your remote name will be `origin` as this is the default, to push to the `master` branch you can execute

```
git push origin master
```

For reference, see the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have committed file but have not pushed them.

In git commit and push is different. You need to push your changes in order to see them in repo

Answer (score 0):

After you commit your project, open git cmd.

Next write your project directory e.g. `cd AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp`

Finally execute `push`, then you can see your changes in github web.